# parsing an MIB text file and generating xml file

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I am developing an snmp manager using snmp4j. I have requirement to read an MIB text file and generate corresponding XML file. Is there any SNMP4j library available to parse the Mib text file and get the data for each object. if snmp4j could not solve my problem, is there any other similar open source is available?

Thanks.

Comment: Either you buy snmp4j MIB support from their home page or you switch to Mibble.

Answer (score 0):

Yep there is one. It is combining the power of snmp4j and mibble and is able to generate nicely structured xml from snmp-walks [iTransformers Labs snmp2xml4j](https://github.com/iTransformers/snmp2xml4j)